# How to delete song from Deezer Queue in Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, deezer

I am making a Deezer Web Player, but I don't know how can I delete a song from Queue, I've implemented it with the DZ.player.playTracks function but, everytiime I reset the Queue and load the new song, the playback stops and restarts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to remove a track from the queue is to clear the whole queue by calling again one of the loading methods (playTracks, playPlaylists, etc.).
It's not possible to seamlessly remove a track from the queue for now.